# How to get navbar to fade in and out

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a navbar that when the user scrolls down the page navbar goes translucent and then if the user mouse hovers over the navbar it repears and then goes out again once they move their mouse off the object. I can't seem to work out how to:

Get the navbar to only fade after mouse leave when the user has scrolled down the page - I don't want it to fade when they are at the top of the screen after they move their mouse off it, only when they are further down in the page.
Make it that if slowly fades out when they move their mouse instead of it straight away going to the set opacity.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75) {
        $('#navBar').css("opacity", 0.3);
    }
    else {
        $('#navBar').css("opacity", 1);
    }
});

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#navBar').live("mouseover", function () {
                $(this).css("opacity", 1);
                });

        $('#navBar').live("mouseleave", function () {
                $(this).css("opacity", 0.3);
                });

    })
```

Comment: Please set up a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75) {
        $('#navBar').css("opacity", 0.3);
    }
    else {
        $('#navBar').css("opacity", 1);
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#navBar').live("mouseover", function () {
            $(this).css("opacity", 1);
            });

    $('#navBar').live("mouseleave", function () {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 75) { // this here
            $(this).css("opacity", 0.3);
        }
    });

})
```

Does that work?

You can add this to your CSS to make it fade in/out gradually:

```
#navBar {
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

This way, every time you change the opacity for the element #navBar, the opacity change should take 2 seconds.

Comment: Yep that works great, thanks heaps. I had tried using that extra line of code but since I'm very new to JavaScript, had no idea where to put it. Do know how to make it fade out slowly?

Comment: You can do $(this).fadeOut("slow") instead of changing the opacity with .css(), but .fadeOut() will make the element fully transparent, I think, so I wouldn't use that if you want the element to still remain visible.

Edited my answer. The CSS approach should work.